# Deploy a web application onto a Windows server using GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are running a GitLab with CI and want to deploy our application onto a Windows server. This will be just a demo system so we are quite open how we run the app later.

Currently we build and test the application. Now we need to stop the old app at the server, bring the new build onto server and start the new app.

I want to use at best the tools from GitLab but this isn't a must and as you can assume I am not so used to GitLab Deploy stuff.
Docker would be also an option.

Do you have some ideas?

Thank you
Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren’t precious about the actual deployment of your web app then the easiest thing to do would just be install a gitlab runner on your test windows host. You should use a shell runner, so it can operate as a “fake user”. You’ll also need to ensure the user the runner is installed as has the right creds to install your app.

Tag this runner so it will run for a particular job, then within your gitlab ci you can take a copy of your build as an artifact (see gitlab ci artifacts).

Artifacts are automatically copied between runners so long as they are within the same pipeline run so you will have accsess to your built web app and can then install it how you like.

Comment: Thanks, quizguy. I will try it this way. GitLab runners are accepted by our IT. So, this way will produce no security questions.